# Prejudiced vs biased

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

How do "prejudiced" and "biased" exactly differ? Sometimes, they are used interchangeably.

Upon consulting the dictionary, I find that "prejudice" is defined in the Cambridge Dictionary as −

> "...an unfair and unreasonable opinion or feeling, especially when formed without enough thought or knowledge". http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prejudice

And "bias" is defined in that Dictionary as −

> "...supporting or opposing a particular person or thing in an unfair way, because of allowing personal opinions to influence your judgment". http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bias

While the words appear overlapping each other at one point, they appear different at other point.

What is the real scope of meaning of each of the two words? Can anybody shed some light.

Comment: You once told me you didn't know how to add a link, the easiest way is to copy the url address and paste it into your answer. E.g. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bias But in the editor toolbox on the right hand side there's a small question mark icon, click on it, you should see a menu item called  [advanced help](http://english.stackexchange.com/editing-help) You'll have acess to clear explanations on how to include links, and format your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for your suggestion. I have included the necessary references from the dictionary. Now, I think the question is ok.

Answer (score 4):

Biased is the more general term. It basically means "tendency". An opinion survey or scientific study can be biased, which means it has a systematic error that skews the results. When applied to a person, biased means that the person tends toward certain views (due to their position, self-interest etc.)

Prejudiced, on the other hand, can mean for example that someone has formed an opinion before knowing all the facts. It tends to have a stronger negative connotation, and can even imply bigotry.

The two terms do overlap in meaning, though, and can sometimes be used interchangeably.